# How to declare class as global in TS?

Tags: typescript

Without duplicating class interface in `global`, I would like to avoid duplicating.

The code below doesn't work:

`lib.ts`

```
export {}
declare global {
  var A: TA
}

type TA = typeof A
class A {
  hi(): void { console.log('hi') }
}

declare let global: any
if (typeof window === 'undefined') global.window = global
window.A = A
```

`app.ts`

```
import './lib.ts'

new A().hi() // Works

interface Some {
  a: A // Error
}
```

The error:

```
'A' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof A'?
```

Comment: I think without [ms/TS#39504](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39504) the only way to make a global class declaration is with a `var`/`type` or `var`/`interface` pair.  So some amount of duplication is currently inevitable. Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, please write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to declare a global `class` from within a module such that both the named constructor value and instance interface type are exposed globally.  There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#39504](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39504) to allow this, but for now it's not part of the language.

The standard way to do this is to introduce a global `var` declaration for the constructor value, and a `type` or `interface` declaration of the same name for the instance type.  For example:

```
export { }
namespace Module {
  export class A { hi(): void { console.log('hi') } }
}
declare global {
  var A: typeof Module.A;
  interface A extends Module.A { }
}
Object.assign(globalThis, Module);
```

Yes, there's some unavoidable redundancy here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwFADsCGBbYBnMTAY2DgFkIATAVwBtSFU45RJY4jbM884BBRHAAWASwAUASgBccAG4QRlQUQjo8EegDpaEAOZiA5KIMSUKVGkrBOmKKV06ARplqImc2-xkwAnmGAQAGbkVHTAmnwA3O4i6DDAUIHEpAKg8eiUvBQ0WgJIaGgA8o4AVtYwmtx4IrroYg4QzrQAKqJ4ADQhOcAS0ahAA)